partial trace of a unitary matrix over the zero state of ancilla qubit
I was going through a paper in which it is written that $\tilde{A}$ is the partial trace of $U$ over the zero state of the ancilla space.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.00081
\begin{equation*}
U|\phi\rangle=|0\rangle^{\otimes a} \otimes \tilde{A}|\psi\rangle+\sqrt{1-\| \tilde{A}|\psi\rangle \|^{2}}\left|\sigma^{\perp}\right\rangle
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{array}{r}
\left(\left\langle\left. 0\right|^{\otimes a} \otimes I_{n}\right)\left|\sigma^{\perp}\right\rangle=0\right. \\
\|\left|\sigma^{\perp}\right\rangle \|=1 
\end{array}

I tried searching a lot about partial trace of a matrix in some quantum computing books to understand the above formula, but could not find anything. It would be really great if I can be helped with partial trace ( and also with some code if possible).

TL;DR
I am sharing your confusion. IMO, the nomenclature "partial trace" is misleading in this case. $A$ is not the result of what is usually called a partial trace over $U$.
What a partial trace usually is
A partial trace is performed for sort of ignoring a quantum subsystem.
For example if you have a state $\rho = |\Phi^+\rangle \langle \Phi^+|$ with $|\Phi^+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$ and you want to ignore the second qubit. Then, you construct
$$\rho_1 = Tr_2 \rho = \langle 0| \rho | 0 \rangle + \langle 1| \rho |1\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle \langle 0| + |1\rangle \langle 1|) $$
Notice, that both $\langle 0|\rho | 0\rangle$ and $\langle 1 |\rho | 1\rangle$ appear in the expression. This what a trace is. You sum over all diagonal matrix elements (not just a fraction of it).
Block encoding
In Block encoding, you encode a (usually) non-unitary matrix $A$ within a unitary $U$ such that $A = \langle 0| U | 0\rangle$ where $|0\rangle$ can stand for multiple ancilla qubits.
Mathematically, $\langle 0| U | 0\rangle$ is not a trace even though it is called a "partial trace of $U$ over the zero state" in the paper.
The idea behind this construction is not to ignore the subsystem of ancillas, but to impose the conditions that the ancilla qubits start in $|0\rangle$ and also must have $0$ measurement outcomes eventually (you can get the latter via post-selection).

Thank you @qubitzer for the response.

Assume the density matrix of a system composed of subsystems $A$ (of size $n$) and $B$ (of size $m$) is given by $\rho_{AB}$. The formal definition of the partial trace over subsystem $A$ (to calculate the reduced density matrix of subsystem $B$) is given by:
$$\rho_B = \text{Tr}_{A} [\rho_{AB}] = \sum_{i=1}^{2^n}\left(\langle\phi_i|\otimes I_A \right)\rho_{AB} \left(|\phi_i\rangle \otimes I_A\right )$$
where the states $\{|\phi_i\rangle\}_{i=1}^{2^m}$ form a basis in subsystem $B$.
This expression has a very intuitive interpretation. The identity matrix $I_A$ is operating over the density matrix $\rho_{AB}$ to "leave subsystem $A$ alone", and the part of the operator consisting of $\langle\phi_j| \, \cdot \,  |\phi_j\rangle$ is computing the probabilities of each of the basis states in subsystem $B$, which are then getting summed up. In other words, this expression is performing an identity on $A$, and "averaging out" (removing) the contribution of $B$ (since probabilities add up to 1).
Compare the expression above with the one you have to compute $\tilde{A}$:
$$\tilde{A} = \text{Tr}_{0^{\otimes a}}[U] = \left(\langle0|^{\otimes a} \otimes I_n \right) U \left(|0\rangle^{\otimes a} \otimes I_n \right).$$
These two expression are extremely similar. The difference is that, in the definition of the partial trace over $A$ you are averaging over all basis states, whereas in the one to compute $\tilde{A}$ you are only considering the component of the first basis state (the all-zeros state $|0\rangle^{\otimes a}$) instead of averaging overall of them.
In a sense, this is a partial trace because you are tracing the all-zeros portion of the first subsystem from the full matrix $U$.

Thank you @diemilio for the response. Can you also provide some link to study partial trace? Also, is partial trace only calculated for Mixed states?

https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhI5X1mNN8ghnH1ckAcclxY6-CPmZvWrk&si=gpvTUNFPIFW60Gr6

Thank you @diemilio. These lectures are excellent.
